# Admin Sales Order Grid Slow

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

i have a magento store, but im having issues with the admin sales order grid, the page sales is very slow, it takes 25 seconds for the page being completed load, and this issue is only in the sales order page in the admin, i have 114000 orders records.

I already have the indexing being fired, cache, disable plugins that are not being used,everything that i found online to do, but still no solution in resolving it, is someone had same situation?

Comment: Facing same problem. Please anyone tell the solution.